# "User cannot be found." error in Powershell

Tags: 2010, permissions, powershell, error, active-directory

I am writing a PowerShell script to re-sync my users to the AD because of a problem I have described [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67476/how-do-i-refresh-each-site-collections-permissions). From time to time I get a "Set-SPUser : user cannot be found." error but when I call the same command again with the same parameters no error appears and it simply works.

I have no problem just writing this line twice so if the error occurs, it'll simply work the second time it is called or even running the script twice in a row. But I prefer to understand this problem.

The code looks like this:

```
$allSiteCollections = Get-SPWebApplication [Web-Application-Name]

foreach ($siteCollection in $allSiteCollections.Sites)
{
    $currentWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteCollection.url

    $members = $currentWeb.SiteGroups["Members"]

    foreach ($currentUser in $members.Users)
    {
        Set-SPUser -Identity $currentUser.UserLogin -Web $currentWeb.url -SyncFromAD -Group "Members"
    }
}
```

This is the line that throws the error:

```
Set-SPUser -Identity $currentUser.UserLogin -Web $currentWeb.url -SyncFromAD -Group "Members"
```

If it throws the error and I re-run it, it works perfectly the second time.

Does anybody have any idea why does this happen?

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Nope. I used user migrate instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this happens but I've seen it before.  So much so that when I built my code on top of this I put a try catch in and had it do the command a second time before I was convinced that I didn't work as expected.